# Node.js - ¿Como conectar de forma simultanea a 2 o más servidores SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, express

Buenas,

¿Alguien me podría indicar si es posible mantener abiertas dos conexiones a dos servidors de SQL Server, usando node.js y express?

Si se puede, ¿cómo lo debería hacer?

Estoy usando el módulo de node mssql v3, para realizar la conexión a la base de datos. He visto que ya existe la versión 4 de mssql.

Actualmente, dispongo de un fichero con la configuración de la base de datos, que también realiza la conexión. Al realizar la conexión con la otra base de datos, la primera conexión queda colgada.

Graias.

Comment: Al parecer es posible, mira en el apartado [pools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection-pools) del README del paquete, allí dice que puedes crear múltiples instancias. Puedes crear un archivo con dos funciones que retorne una conexión a cada servidor y usar el que se desea.

Comment: Sí se puede. El conector es un objeto y se pueden crear tantas instancias de ese objeto como se deseen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionado! Actualizé a la versión 4 de mssql, y funciona sin ningún problema.

```
var debug = require('debug')('app:dbConn');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const sql = require('mssql');

//BASE DE DADES REAL
const config1 = { server: "IP1", database: "DB1", user: "foo", password: "foopass", port: 1433 };
const config2 = { server: "IP2", database: "DB2", user: "foo2", password: "foopass2", port: 1433 };
// Conexions

const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config1)
pool1.connect()
    .then(function() { 
        debug('Connected to SQL Server1');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        debug('Error connect SQL Server1\n %O', err);
    })

const pool2 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config2)
pool2.connect()
    .then(function() { 
        debug('Connected to SQL Server2');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        debug('Error connect SQL Server2\n %O', err);
    });


module.exports = {"DB1": pool1, "DB2": pool2}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, quisiera realizar una pregunta referente a esta conexión múltiple, debo realizar una conexión similar, la diferencia que tengo, es que debo hacer una conexión con mogodb (librería usada: mongoose), alguien sabe como se puede realizar dicha conexión.

Comment: tienes que connectar a dos mongodb o solo a 1?  
Si solo és a 1 en https://mongoosejs.com/ tienes la información de como hacer la conexión. Justo cuando abres la web te explica como connectar

Comment: Debo realizar la conexión de 2 mongos, cada uno se encuentra en un servidor diferente.

Comment: @Brayan esto lo hice una vez pero no me acuerdo como lo hice. Solo era una prueba  y no guardé el código.

Mirate estas webs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project
https://medium.com/@rajamanii/connecting-multiple-database-in-nodejs-with-mongodb-and-mongoose-d88574fcd5a3
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#mongos_connections